# Move a Image in a div (like dragging)

Tags: jquery, html, upload, drag-and-drop, image-uploading

I've got that demo [here](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload), and I was trying to make draggable the uploaded image inside a div.

Sol What I want is :

first - Upload and image
2nd -  after loading such image into that div ( #holder), the img must be draggable (always inside the #holder div ).

I've been trying with JQuery script :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
         $( "#holder > img" ).draggable();
         $( "#holder > img" ).scalable();
         $( "#holder > img" ).resizable({ alsoResize: "#mirror" });
    });

    </script>
```

Why is not working, I added that script after the script of the first step :(

So, I just wanna move the image.Why is not right doing $("#holders > img").draggable() or $("#holders > img").childre().draggable() ???

SOLVED ::::  --> It was pretty simple ¬¬   Just writting  `$( "#holder > img" ).draggable();` after dropping the image hahahaha

'Cause I was doing when document onload it was a very big mistake. Sorryyyyyy & Thanks

Comment: Did you add jQuery UI? In the html


`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sure dude, I did a test. :D

Comment: yes. I think the problem is that when I start dragging the uploaded image It takes as if it was a nem image and It puts again in the center of the div. How could I prevent this ???

Comment: I don't know. Never happened with me.

Comment: You mean you get like a ghost image under your cursor and the image is still in the div? And could show your html as well.

Comment: Yes. Try it completely depends on the OS. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use draggable on the parent element of what you want dragged. so

`$("#holder").draggable()`

Comment: No, no I just wanna move the image is not right doing $("#holders > img").draggable() or $("#holders > img").childre().draggable() ???

Comment: is the img element a direct child of #holder? as thats what > is means all img elements that are immediate children of #holder.

Comment: Then like i have in the answer you need $("#holder").draggable(), that makes the images draggable. The image never "leaves" #holder dom it just gets a position:absolute style

Comment: this is not what want. This makes the div container (#holder) draggable. I what I want is to move it's children.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this website it's [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/). Where they include even example with source code.

I guess this is what you exactly need.[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: Yes, I've already did it, it's exactly what I've done : $("#holders > img").draggable() or $("#holders > img").childre().draggable() @iraycd

Comment: No, 'cause I need the images to be visibles :(

Comment: yes. I think the problem is that when I start dragging the uploaded image It takes as if it was a nem image and It puts again in the center of the div.     How could I prevent this ???